# jqGrid inline deleting the row using clienArray

Tags: jqgrid

```
                 $('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
                      //  the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
                       { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: false },
                       // options for the Edit Dialog
                       {
                           editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
                           recreateForm: true,
                           checkOnUpdate: true,
                           checkOnSubmit: true,
                           closeAfterEdit: true,
                          //   afterShowForm: PayTypeValidation,
                           errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                               return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                           }
                       },
                       // options for the Add Dialog
                       {
                           closeAfterAdd: true,
                           recreateForm: true,
                          // afterShowForm: PayTypeValidation,
                           errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                               return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                           }
                       },
//delete
{
 errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                                   return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                               }
}
});
```

Above is the code for add and edit but the delete section doesnot work,please suggest the code for inline delete of row in grid with clientarray

Comment: You wrote about "using clienArray" and posted no code of jqGrid. Do you mean that you use `editurl: "clientArray"`? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? In general the `errorTextFormat` is introduced to display *server side error* for the client.

Comment: jqGrid version is  4.4.4,yes am using edit url:'clientArray' and datatype:json. In the code mentioned above i can add and edit the grid but deleting i have no code